# Between today and 7 days in the future

Tags: wordpress

I am using PHP `7.3.5` and `wordpress 5.2.x`.

I have the following query, which gives me everything that is greater than `today`:

```
    $today = new DateTime();
    $timestToday = $today->getTimestamp();
    try {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'Calendar-Events',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // add -1 here for all posts
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_key' => 'timestamp',
            //'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            //'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'timestamp',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $timestToday,
                ),
            ),
        );

        $upcomingEvents = new WP_Query($args);
```

Any suggestions how to limit my result set by only getting back what is `+7 days` in the future?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: If you add one more param. you can easily handle

Comment: have you any query? I have one more way to achieve your posts if you not satisfied with the answer please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$today = new DateTime();
$Today = $today->getTimestamp();    
$Futuredate = date("Ymd", strtotime($Today."+7 days"));

try {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Calendar-Events',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // add -1 here for all posts
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'timestamp',
        //'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        //'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_start_date',
                'value' => array( $Today, $Futuredate ),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
        ),
    );

    $upcomingEvents = new WP_Query($args);
```

For your better understanding please visit this [link](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/query-between-dates-using-date-picker-fields/)